# How with XLSX npm package add custom headers with color

Tags: javascript, excel, xlsx

I'm new to using [XLSX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) package and I'm not quite sure how to create a specific header, with colors and group-specific columns.

I need to do something as the visual example

[image]

Under a header, I can have several columns and the title has a color.
The columns are not fixed for every header so we can have a title with 2 columns under another one with 5 columns.

I started something basic and shared my code but I don't know how to make the headers as an example. The code is for a report extractor in XLS in a project I'm working on

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx';
import moment from 'moment';

const rawToHeaders = ({
  id,
  externalIds,
  dateOfBirth = {},
  postalCode,
  locale,
  siteId,
  status = {},
  prescreenerMetrics,
}) => {
  const { day, month, year } = dateOfBirth;
  const dob = [day, month, year].filter(Boolean).join('-');
  const { type, label, comment, timestamp } = status;
  const timeInStatus = moment(timestamp).toNow(true);

  const N_A = 'not available';

  return {
    'Candidate ID': id,
    'External IDs': externalIds
      ?.map(({ source, value }) => `${source}: ${value}`)
      .join('; '),
    'Date of birth': dob,
    'Postal code': postalCode,
    Locale: locale,
    'Site ID': siteId,
    'Current status': type,
    'Current sub-status': label,
    'Current status comment': comment,
    'Time in current status': timeInStatus,
    'Source/recruiter': prescreenerMetrics?.source,
    Referrer: prescreenerMetrics?.referrer,
  };
};

const generateMasterReport = (data) => {
  const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

  const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data.map(rawToHeaders));

  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws);

  return XLSX.write(wb, { type: 'buffer', bookType: 'xlsx' });
};

export default generateMasterReport;
```

From the code above let's say I want to group the columns under specific headers with color

The columns are 12 so 4 headers and in the order, as are in the code like

- HEADER 1: Candidate ID, External ID, Date of birth -- RED
- HEADER 2: Postal code, Locale, Site ID -- BLUE
- HEADER 3: Site ID, current status, current sub status -- GREEN
- HEADER 4: Time in status, Source, Referrer -- WHITE

I was able to create the excel without the headers for now but this part I'm not sure how to do it

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem and I don't know if it is the best :)
However, worked for me so I'm sharing

Below code of what I did, I put the headers in a variable that is used to create the headers and I used the "merge" from documentation to create the merged cells of the headers.

What I don't know is how to make this more functional and how to make a with for single columns instead of a global one as

`const colWidths = [{ wch: 12 }];`

I would like to customize every column to a specific width.

Another thing I believe without the pro version of the PKG I cannot style the cells with a different font, BGColor, and so on but if there is a way I'm ear :)

```
import XLSX from 'xlsx';
import moment from 'moment';

const N_A = null;

const headerGroups = [
  { name: 'Candidate data', origin: 'A1' },
  { name: 'Date receiving status', origin: 'N1' },
  { name: 'Candidate in Pending call center status', origin: 'U1' },
  {
    name: 'Candidate in Pending site OR Consented OR Randomized status',
    origin: 'AI1',
  },
];

const colWidths = [{ wch: 12 }];

const rawToHeaders = ({
  id,
  externalIds,
  dateOfBirth = {},
  postalCode,
  locale,
  siteId,
  status = {},
  prescreenerMetrics,
}) => {
  const { day, month, year } = dateOfBirth;
  const dob = [day, month, year].filter(Boolean).join('-');
  const { type, label, comment, timestamp } = status;
  const timeInStatus = moment(timestamp).toNow(true);
  return {
    // !Candidate data
    'Candidate ID': id,
    'External IDs': externalIds
      ?.map(({ source, value }) => `${source}: ${value}`)
      .join('; '),
    'Date of birth': dob,
    'Postal code': postalCode,
    Locale: locale,
    'Site ID': siteId,
    'PI name': N_A,
    'Current status': type,
    'Current sub-status': label,
    'Current status comment': comment,
    'Time in current status': timeInStatus,
    'Source/recruiter': prescreenerMetrics?.source,
    Referrer: prescreenerMetrics?.referrer,
    // !Date receiving status
    'Pending call center': N_A,
    'Pending site': N_A,
    Consented: N_A,
    Randomized: N_A,
    'Rejected call center': N_A,
    'Rejected  site (+ rejected_consented + rejected_randomized)': N_A,
    'Call Scheduled': N_A,
    // !Candidate in Pending call center status
    'Call - Attempts (by call center)': N_A,
    'SMS - Attempts (by call center)': N_A,
    'Email - Attempts (by call center)': N_A,
    'Phone number revealed (by call center) - quantity': N_A,
    'Email revealed (by call center) - quantity': N_A,
    'Call - date of first attempt (by call center)': N_A,
    'SMS - date of first attempt (by call center)': N_A,
    'Email - date of first attempt (by call center)': N_A,
    'Call - duration of longest call (by call center)': N_A,
    'Call - date of longest call (by call center)': N_A,
    'Comments (by call center) in Trialbee system': N_A,
    'Last staff activity (by call center) - Action': N_A,
    'Last staff activity by call center - User': N_A,
    'Last staff activity by call center - Date': N_A,
    // !Candidate in Pending site OR Consented OR Randomized status
    'Call - attempts (by site)': N_A,
    'SMS - attempts (by site)': N_A,
    'Email - attempts (by site)': N_A,
    'Phone number revealed (by site) - quantity': N_A,
    'Email revealed (by site) - quantity': N_A,
    'Call - date of first attempt (by site)': N_A,
    'SMS - date of first attempt (by site)': N_A,
    'Email - date of first attempt by site': N_A,
    'Call - Longest duration of call (by site)': N_A,
    'Call - Date of longest call (by site)': N_A,
    'Comments (by site) in Trialbee system': N_A,
    'Last staff activity (by site) - Action': N_A,
    'Last staff activity (by site) - User': N_A,
    'Last staff activity (by site) - Date': N_A,
  };
};

const generateMasterReport = (data) => {
  const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
  const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data.map(rawToHeaders), { origin: 'A2' });
  ws['!merges'] = [
    XLSX.utils.decode_range('A1:M1'),
    XLSX.utils.decode_range('N1:T1'),
    XLSX.utils.decode_range('U1:AH1'),
    XLSX.utils.decode_range('AI1:AV1'),
  ];
  headerGroups.forEach(({ name, origin }) => {
    XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, [[name]], { origin });
  });

  ws['!cols'] = colWidths;

  XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws);

  return XLSX.write(wb, { type: 'buffer', bookType: 'xlsx' });
};

export default generateMasterReport;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Width of Each column by giving `wch` value in an array

```
const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();

const colWidths = [{ wch: 12 },{ wch: 20 },{ wch: 25 },{ wch: 30 },{ wch: 40 }];

ws['!cols'] = colWidths;

XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws);
```

Comment: It increases the width but it does not customise the header of column.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the different package instead of XLSX , if you want to set only header color then you have to install => **npm i xlsx-color**

```
const exportToExcel = (data , fileName) =>{
    const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const fileExtension = '.xlsx';

const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data);
ws['A1'].s = {
  fill: {
    patternType: 'solid',
    fgColor: { rgb: 'FF939393' }
  },
  font: {
    name: 'Times New Roman',
    sz: 16,
    color: { rgb: '#FF000000' },
    bold: false,
    italic: false,
    underline: false
  }
};
const wb = { Sheets: { data: ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
const excelData = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: fileType });
FileSaver.saveAs(excelData, fileName + ' - ' + dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY') + fileExtension);
}
```